# JS não formatando o valor de milhar corretamente para o Input e nem recebendo corretamente no PHP / Banco de Dados

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, valor-monetário

Bom dia pessoal, tenho em meu formulários alguns input's onde o usuário informa o valor do produto, a sua quantidade e com isso é feito o cálculo do Valor do Produto e também do Valor Total do Pedido simultâneamente. O campo de Valor e Quantidade renderiza os valores de milhar normalmente, mas estes valores não chegam da maneira correta no PHP, por exemplo, o valor de 1.000,00 chega como 1.00 no PHP, e o valor do Valor do Produto e Valor do Pedido que é calculado pelo JS também ocorre a mesma coisa, até 999,99 ele apresenta normalmente e após o milhar ele já não funciona. Alguem consegue me dizer onde estou errando no calculo e no recebimento dos dados no PHP ?

Estrutura HTML dos Input's:

```
<div class="clone-prod" name="clone-prod[]">

                                    <div class="wrap-prod" name="wrap-prod[]">

                                        <div class="produtos-wrap" name="produtos-wrap[]">
                                            <div class="text-center select_height produto-padrao" id="primeiro-produto">
                                                <input type="text" class="index font-pop input-div" id="index_produto"
                                                    name="index_produto[]" value="1" readonly="true" required>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="text-center select_height produto-padrao" id="segundo-produto">
                                                <input class="font-pop number_id_produto input-div" value=""
                                                    readonly="true" name="id_produto[]" required>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="text-center select_height produto-padrao terceiro-produto"
                                                id="terceiro-produto" name="terceiro-produto[]">
                                                <select class="selectpicker form-control" data-show-subtext="false"
                                                    data-live-search="true" name="select_produtos[]"
                                                    id="select_produtos" onchange="initProdutos(this)" required>
                                                    <?php
                                                    echo '<option disabled selected hidden
                                                    value="Selecione um produto..."
                                                    data-subtext="Selecione um produto...">Selecione um produto...
                                                    </option>';
                                                    foreach ($res as $item_produtos) {
                                                        echo '<option data-subtext="' . $item_produtos['CODACESSO'] . '" value="'
                                                        . $item_produtos['CODACESSO'] . "|" . $item_produtos['EMBALAGEM'] . "|" 
                                                        . $item_produtos['QTDEMBALAGEM'] . '">' . $item_produtos['DESCCOMPLETA'] . '</option>';
                                                    }
                                                    ?>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="text-center select_height produto-padrao" id="quantidade-embalagem">
                                                <input type="text" class="edit-input font-pop"
                                                    name="qtdembalagem[]" value="" required>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="text-center select_height produto-padrao" id="quarto-produto">
                                                <input type="text" maxlength="2" class="edit-input font-pop"
                                                    name="embalagem[]" value="" required>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="text-center select_height produto-padrao" id="quinto-produto">
                                                <input type="number" id="preco-input" name="preco[]" step="0.01" min="0"
                                                    class="edit-input font-pop" required>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="text-center select_height produto-padrao" id="sexto-produto">
                                                <input type="number" id="qtd-input" step="0.01" min="0"
                                                    class="edit-input font-pop" value="" name="quantidade-produto[]"
                                                    required>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="text-center select_height produto-padrao" id="setimo-produto">
                                                <input class="font-pop preco-produto input-div" readonly="true"
                                                    name="preco-produto[]" required>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="text-center select_height produto-padrao oitavo-produto"
                                            id="div-remove">
                                            <button type="button"
                                                class="remover glyphicon glyphicon-remove button-produto"></button>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                </div>

                            </section>
                            <div id="wrap-addbutton">
                                <button type="button" id="add-button"
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign button-produto"></button>
                                <b>Adicione um produto...</b>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="container" id="produto-total">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="assinatura col-lg-9">
                                <div id="wrap-assinatura" class="text-center">
                                    <div id="assinatura"></div>
                                    <b>Assinatura</b>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="preco-final col-lg-12 text-right">
                                <b>Preço Total:</b>
                                <br>
                                <input id="total" readonly="true" name="total_pedido" class="text-right input-div"
                                    value="R$ 0.00">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Funções JS de Cálculo:

```
$(document).ready().on("input", "[name='preco[]'], [name='quantidade-produto[]']", function () {

    // pega a div principal
    var wraper = $(this).closest(".produtos-wrap");

    // pega a quantidade
    var qtd_produto = $("[name='quantidade-produto[]']", wraper).val();

    // pega o preço
    var preco_produto = $("[name='preco[]']", wraper).val().replace(',', '.');

    // div com o valor do produto
    var total_produto = $("[name='preco-produto[]']", wraper);

    // coloca o valor total do produto
    total_produto.val(formataMoeda(qtd_produto * preco_produto));

    calculos(); // chama a função para calcular o total geral
});


function calculos() {
    // variável do total
    var total = 0;
    // soma tudo e coloca na div do total
    $("[name='preco-produto[]']").each(function () {
        // pega apenas o valor e ignora o "R$"
        var p = parseFloat($(this).val().match(/[\d|,|\.]+/)[0].replace(/\./g, "").replace(",", "."));
        total += p;
    });
    // coloca o valor total na div "total"
    $("#total").val(formataMoeda(total));
}


function formataMoeda(v) {
    return v.toLocaleString('pt-BR', { style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' });
}
```

Forma que Recebo os Dados no PHP e também Envio ao Banco:

```
<?php
include 'verifica_login.php';
include 'conexao.php';

error_reporting(E_ERROR);
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

# Inclusão do Pedido


$id_fornecedor = $_POST['fornecedor_id'];

$nome_fornecedor = trim($_POST['select_fornecedor']);

$nome_input_fornecedor = trim($_POST['fornecedor_new_input']);

$cnpj = str_replace(".", "", str_replace("/", "", str_replace("-", "", $_POST['cnpj'])));

preg_match('/[\d|,|\.]+/', $_POST['total_pedido'], $valor_total);
$valor_total = str_replace(",", ".", str_replace(".", "", $valor_total[0]));

$gerente_fiscal = trim($_SESSION['nome']);

$loja = trim($_POST['loja']);

if (isset($_POST['change_fornecedor'])) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (NULL, '$gerente_fiscal', '$id_fornecedor', '$nome_input_fornecedor','$cnpj', NOW(), '$valor_total', '$loja')";
    if (!$connect->query($sql) === true) {
        die("Erro na inserção de pedido: " . $sql . "<br>" . $connect->error);
    }
} else {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (NULL, '$gerente_fiscal', '$id_fornecedor', '$nome_fornecedor', '$cnpj', NOW(), '$valor_total', '$loja')";
    if (!$connect->query($sql) === true) {
        die("Erro na inserção de pedido: " . $sql . "<br>" . $connect->error);
    }
}

# Inserção de Itens de Pedido
$id_pedido = $connect->insert_id;
$qtd_itens = sizeof($_POST['index_produto']);
for ($i=0; $i < $qtd_itens; $i++) {
    # Variáveis
    $item = $_POST['index_produto'][$i];

    $id_produto = $_POST['id_produto'][$i];

    $desc_produto = $_POST['select_produtos'][$i];

    preg_match('/[\d|,|\.]+/', $_POST['quantidade-produto'][$i], $quantidade);
    $quantidade = str_replace(",", ".", str_replace(".", "", $quantidade[0]));;

    preg_match('/[\d|,|\.]+/', $_POST['preco'][$i], $valor_un);
    $valor_un = str_replace(",", ".", str_replace(".", "", $valor_un[0]));

    preg_match('/[\d|,|\.]+/', $_POST['preco-produto'][$i], $valor_produto);
    $valor_produto = str_replace(",", ".", str_replace(".", "", $valor_produto[0]));

    # Insert de Dados

    $query = "INSERT INTO pedido_item VALUES ('$id_pedido', '$item', '$id_produto', '$desc_produto', '$valor_un', '$quantidade', '$valor_produto')";
    if (!$connect->query($query) === true) {
        die("Erro na inserção de itens: " . $query . "<br>" . $connect->error);
    }
}

header('Location: principal.php');
```

Agradeço a qualquer ajuda fornecida.

Comment: Acabei de postar a pergunta e já votaram de forma negativa, poderiam pelo menos vim comentar o que acharam negativo na pergunta...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há algumas incorreções no código JS e no PHP. No JS você está usando no `toLocaleString` o formato `en-US` quando deveria ser `pt-BR` para sair no formato `R$ 1.000,00`:

```
return v.toLocaleString('pt-BR', { style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' });
```

Na linha que soma os valores, é preciso remover todos os pontos de milhar com `.replace(/\./g, "")`:

```
var p = parseFloat($(this).val().match(/[\d|,|\.]+/)[0].replace(/\./g, "").replace(",", "."));
```

Na parte do PHP, basta usar a mesma lógica do JS para formatar o valor. Por exemplo, se o valor for `R$ 3.000.000,00` (três milhões), o resultado esperado é: `3000000.00`, então é só usar um `preg_match` com 2 replaces para remover os pontos e substituir a vírgula por um ponto:

```
preg_match('/[\d|,|\.]+/', $_POST['total_pedido'], $valor_total);
$valor_total = str_replace(",", ".", str_replace(".", "", $valor_total[0]));
```

Comment: Sam, para os valores de milhar funcionou, mas agora os valores decimais ficaram diferentes, se eu coloco um preço de por exemplo 54,50, ele vai com o valor de 5450.00 para o BD. Eu usei o mesmo preg_match e a mesma lógica do valor_total que você passou para o valor_un, quantidade e valor_produto, pois estes podem ter os mesmo casos.

Comment: Blz... vou dar uma olhada

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta para a maneira que está meu código no momento para ficar mais fácil @Sam.

Comment: Pronto @Sam, editei a pergunta para o código atual...

Comment: Vc só vai usar o preg_match nos campos que possuem a formatação do toLocaleString, que é o $_POST['total_pedido'] e o $_POST['preco-produto'][$i]... os outros não precisa porque já vão no formato correto.

Comment: Em questão do $_POST['preco-produto'][$i], a forma que utilizei está correta ? Pois nele existe o loop enquanto no total_pedido não existe. Mas bom, corrigindo o resto já ficará correto ?

Comment: Acredito que sim.

Comment: Fiz o teste e deu certo @Sam, muito obrigado <3 !

Answer (score 0):

Você está substituindo a vírgula por ponto, porém não está retirando o ponto que em pt-br é o separador de milhar. Assim a conversão para decimal para logo no primeiro ponto (o de milhar que não foi retirado) e '1.000.00' vira '1.00'.

Portanto deve-se primeiro tirar os pontos:

```
function desformataMoeda(strMoeda) {
   // pega apenas o valor e ignora o "R$"
   return parseFloat(strMoeda.match(/[\d|,|\.]+/)[0].replace(/\./g, '').replace(",", ".").replace(",", "."));
}
...
// pega o preço
var preco_produto = desformataMoeda($("[name='preco[]']", wraper).val());
...
var p = desformataMoeda($(this).val());
```